# Volume of solid of rotation - can you always get same answer using shell or disk-washer?

Tags: calculus

The question is to find the volume of revolution of the region bonded by $x=0$ and $y=10$ and $y=8$ and $xy=8$ when rotated about the $x$ axis.

Using the Shell method is almost trivial:

$V=2 \pi \int y (8/y)dy $ with bounds from $8$ to $10$.  The y variables cancel and the answer is $32 \pi$.

I'm having difficulty doing this with the disk-washer method.

Is it always possible to achieve the correct answer using both methods?

Comment: Yes, though one of them may be significantly harder to apply than the other. In this case you’ll need to split the washer calculation into two parts, one from $x=0$ to $x=\frac45$ and one from $x=\frac45$ to $x=1$: $x=\frac45$ is where the hyperbola intersects $y=10$, and $x=1$ is where it intersects $y=8$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

For disk method, you are considering radius along $y$ axis and that is not defined by the same curves throughout $8 \leq y \leq 10$.

$xy = 8 \implies x = 1 $ when $y = 8$.

$xy = 8 \implies x = \frac{8}{10} $ when $y = 10$.

For $0 \leq x \leq \frac{4}{5}$, the radius of revolution is defined by lines $y = 8$ and $y = 10$.

For $\frac{4}{5} \leq x \leq 1$, the radius of revolution has lower bound of $y = 8$ and upper bound of $y = \frac{8}{x}$ which is hyperbola curve.

So volume of revolution using disk method,

$\displaystyle \int_0^{4/5} \int_8^{10} 2\pi r \ dr \ dx + \int_{4/5}^{1} \int_8^{8/x} 2\pi r \ dr \ dx$

Comment: I didn't understand the double integrals part, but when I integrated it from 0 to .8 and then from .8 to 1 it produced 28.8pi + 3.2 pi = 32pi which was the original answer by the shell method.

Comment: sure I will try and help. Is your question why we are dividing the integral into two or the limits of both of them?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it always possible to achieve the correct answer using both methods?

It depends on what you mean by "achieve."
Both methods should always give the same answer--when the integral can be evaluated explicitly by both methods.
However, it may be that one antiderivative may not have an elementary expression, or that the limits of integration cannot be expressed by elementary antiderivatives, and so the volume requires the use of special functions to calculate (or approximate) if the "wrong" method is selected.

One simple example would be the area produced by revolving the region $0 \leq x \leq 1, x^5 + x \leq y \leq 2$ about the $y$-axis:
[image: A solid of revolution whose volume cannot be found with elementary functions using disk integration.]
Even writing down the integrand to evaluate this volume via disk integration requires [Bring radicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical), which are not elementary functions: $$\text{Volume } = \pi \int_0^2 BR(y)^2 dy.$$ It's debatable at best whether computing the volume of this solid via the disk method is "achievable."

Yet if we set this up using shell integration instead, any second-semester high-school calculus student can evaluate the resulting volume integral easily: $$\text{Volume } = 2\pi \int_0^1 x (2 - x^5 - x) dx = 2\pi [x^2 - \frac{x^7}{7} - \frac{x^3}{3}]_0^1 = \frac{22 \pi}{21}.$$ Perhaps there's some clever substitution which could be used to evaluate the disk integral above, in which case we *would* get the same answer of $\frac{22 \pi}{21}$.
But I'm pretty sure that any such substitution would in fact end up being a thinly (or not-so-thinly) disguised version of the shell integral, regardless.